# Flash CS3 + AS 3.0 Mute and unmute stage volume

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

Can someone please help quickly mute or unmute the stage volume in Flash CS3 using AS 3.0.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](http://schoolofflash.com/2008/03/tutorial-using-sound-in-actionscript-3/). There are a lot out there I guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want is the SoundMixer class. Just set it's soundTransform object like this:

Mute:

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
```

Unmute:

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this line into your script when you want to stop the sound:

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```