# How to mute audio (sound) using ToggleSwitch on Adobe Flex mobile (spark)?

Tags: android, apache-flex, audio, mute

I want to learn how to turn off (mute) the sound using ToggleSwitch component in Adobe Flash Builder 4.6. I plan to use the Android application.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362379/flash-cs3-as-3-0-mute-and-unmute-stage-volume

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "**ToggleButton**" to the stage and right-click it and choose "**Generate click handler**" and then paste this code.

```
protected function ToggleBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(ToggleBtn.label)
        {
            case "Mute":
                SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
                ToggleBtn.label="UnMute";
                break;
            case "UnMute":
                SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
                ToggleBtn.label="Mute";
                break;
        }
}
```